# Can i delay the loading of certain divs using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Let's say I have a page with 2 divs.  In the first div I have a video.  After the video plays the 30 second clip THEN i want the second div to show an "about video" text.  How can i accomplish this?

Code:

```
 <div class="clip"> (This is the first div)
 <video width="560" height="340" controls>
 <source src="media/clip.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
 <source src="media/clip.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
 </video>
 </div>

 <div class="about_video"> (This is the second div)
 Clip by Person.  The clip is about sample..
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/frictionless/NNCRR/

The top bar appears after a delay of 5000 milliseconds or 5 seconds

```
$(function() {

   $('.headerbar')       
    .delay(5000).slideDown();

});​
```

Hope this helps

For more check http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Just note that this will make the div appear after 5 seconds..This solution no way know whether the video has been running for that about of time.

Comment: The invisible [tag:jQuery] tag strikes again.

Comment: Both vars are useless in this answer.

Comment: @frictionlesspulley if i have a <div> within headerbar i guess the script won't work? I have something like that and it won't render it..

Comment: Is there something else other than slidedown? Can't i just make it appear where it's suppose to be rather than sliding down?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

**HTML** (ID's are your friend):

```
 <div id="div1" class="clip"> (This is the first div)
     <video id="myVideo" width="560" height="340" controls>
         <source src="media/clip.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
         <source src="media/clip.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
     </video>
 </div>

 <div id="div2" class="about_video"> (This is the second div)
     Clip by Person.  The clip is about sample..
 </div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.about_video {
    display: 'none';
}
```

**JS**:

```
document.getElementById('myVideo').addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('div2').style.display = 'block';
});
```